# A way to use switch, to check if "url/file" is present in "url/file?get.php? [request uri]

Tags: php, url, switch-statement, case, strpos

I'm trying to detect when a url is "localhost/asignaciones" but the url changes when i submit something by a button so it leaves it like this "localhost/asignaciones?asg=2222"
so case "/asignaciones" is false

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


    switch ($url) {
    case "/asignaciones?ireelevant_stuff":
    $asignaciones = 'active_button';
    $combinaciones = 'unactive_button';
    break;
    case:
    $asignaciones = 'unactive_button';
    $combinaciones = 'active_button';
    }
```

sorry, i don't know how to explain it better.

thanks @user3783243

the fixed code:

```
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];     
$asiguri = 'asignaciones'; 
$comburi = 'combinaciones';
$legauri = 'legajos';
$inicuri = '/';
switch (true) {
    case strpos($url,$asiguri) === 1: //when $url = '/asignaciones' strpos returns '0' so 'asignaciones' returns '1'. when it returns 1 the code executes until the break
        $asignaciones = 'active_button';
        $combinaciones = $legajos = $inicio = 'unactive_button';

        break;
    case strpos($url,$comburi) === 1:
        $asignaciones = $legajos = $inicio = 'unactive_button';
        $combinaciones = 'active_button';
        break;
    case strpos($url,$legauri) === 1:
        $asignaciones = $combinaciones = $inicio = 'unactive_button';
        $legajos = 'active_button';
        break;
    case strpos($url, $inicuri) === 0: //leave at last because '/' is present in every other
        $asignaciones = $combinaciones = $legajos = 'unactive_button';
        $inicio = 'active_button';
        break;
    default:
        $asignaciones = $combinaciones = $legajos = $inicio = 'unactive_button';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want you'd need to pass in `TRUE` as the `switch` value to check then pass in evaluations on the cases.

```
switch (true) {
    case ($url == "/asignaciones?ireelevant_stuff"):
        $asignaciones = 'active_button';
        $combinaciones = 'unactive_button';
    break;
    case ($url == "otherpath"):
        $asignaciones = 'unactive_button';
        $combinaciones = 'active_button';
    break;
}
```

The manual also has an example of this in the user contributions, https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php#9610.

Comment: The irrelevant stuff can be any combination of letters and numbers, so I want to check only if /asignaciones exist, so every /asignaciones?xxx results true

Comment: @ThiagoschPurpura Use `preg_match` or `strpos` in the `case` in that case. Between the `case` and `:` you can use any evaluation. If it returns `true` you will enter the block and that execution path will be fired until a `break` is encountered.

Comment: When I get some time I'll try it, for what I see that would work, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some mistakes in your code.

To check if your url contains a string you can use `strpos` PHP function, like that:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if (strpos($url, '/asignaciones') !== false) {
    // The string $url contains "/asignaciones"
    $asignaciones = 'active_button';
    $combinaciones = 'unactive_button';
} else {
    // The string $url DOES NOT contain "/asignaciones"
    $asignaciones = 'unactive_button';
    $combinaciones = 'active_button';
}
```